# Set Default Value for Country and State in cart page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, checkout, cart, shopping-cart

as per my requirement, the state and country in the cart page should be a default of US and Washington. I found a configuration for the default of country but I wasn't able to find any for the state. I research and found only for checkout page.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Store -> Configuration -> Sales -> Shipping Setting**

and here set default address as per your need.

[image]